# Having a problem with IMAGE datatype and duplicated records which make query run for minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I know the `IMAGE` datatype is deprecated, but that is how the database I am working in is set-up, and I cannot change it.

I have an `Invoice` table, which records every order that is made.

That `Invoice` table is joined to `Invoice_Details`, which has information about the line items in the invoice.

Then we further join tables based on the `Style` table which is the item master table and has all information about that item specifically, like color, category, size, etc.

Here is the initial query.

```
SELECT 
    I.[Company_Code]
    ,I.[Division_Code]
    ,s.Item_Number
    ,s.Color_Code
    ,s.License_Code
    ,s.Master_Item
    ,i.Date_Invoiced
    ,id.Quantity * id.Price total
    ,Year(i.Date_Invoiced) Year
    ,DATEPART(Quarter, (i.Date_Invoiced)) Quarter
    ,ss.upc_number
    ,ss.size_description 
INTO 
    #SELLINS
FROM 
    [AMTPLUS].[dbo].[Invoices] i
LEFT JOIN
    invoices_detail id ON i.Company_Code = id.Company_Code 
                       AND i.Division_Code = id.Division_Code 
                       AND i.Invoice_Number = id.Invoice_Number
JOIN
    style s ON id.Item_Number = s.Item_Number 
            AND id.Color_Code = s.Color_Code
JOIN
    License ON s.License_Code = License.License_Code
JOIN
    Style_Size ss ON s.Item_Number = ss.Item_Number 
                  AND s.Color_Code = ss.Color_Code
WHERE
    i.Date_Invoiced BETWEEN '01/01/2022' AND '12/30/2022'

SELECT * FROM #SELLINS
```

This line:

```
SELECT * FROM #SELLINS
```

returns 500,000 rows and it does so within 45 seconds, which is reasonable enough.

Now the problem comes in when I want to join the `Style_Image` table, which has an `IMAGE` datatype for each item.

I have been playing around and altering this query a lot, but I cannot make any progress.

One thing I tried to do is separate the image part by itself. So in my stored procedure, the next lines after the above are:

```
SELECT
    s.Item_Number
    ,s.Color_Code
    ,sp.Item_Image
INTO 
    #Sellins2
FROM
    Style S
LEFT JOIN
    Style_Pictures sp ON s.Item_Number = sp.Item_Number 
                      AND s.Color_Code = sp.Color_Code 
                      AND s.Company_Code = sp.Company_Code 
                      AND s.Division_Code = sp.Division_Code
WHERE
    s.Item_Number IN (SELECT DISTINCT Item_Number FROM #SELLINS)

SELECT * FROM #Sellins2
```

I used to have everything on one main query with all the table joins, but to improve performance, I'm trying to split things up.

The

```
Select * from #Sellins2
```

line runs in about 30 seconds, and returns 5,000 lines.

Because while there might be 500,000 records about invoices and the items on each invoice, those are spread out over about 5,000 total items, which get repeated a lot on different invoices.

For example, lots of different people can buy Style A, spread over different invoices, but Style A only has one record on the Image table, since it only has one image.

The problem comes when I try to combine these 2 temporary tables.

The last part of my stored procedure looks like this

```
select 
    s.*
    ,s2.Item_Image
from 
    #Sellins s
    left join #Sellins2 s2 on s.Item_Number=s2.Item_Number and s.Color_Code=s2.Color_Code
```

It takes the image from the #Sellins2 table, and has to attach it to each invoice record, so each of the 500,000 lines shows what is the image that is associated to that line.

That final query, it starts displaying the results instantly, but the lines load in very slowly. And the query only finishes running after 5-10 minutes. Which causes the report to time out when showing it in the SSRS report viewer.

I think the reason this is happening is because even though there are only 5,000 image records, they are getting duplicated each time that item appears. So if a particular item was bought 500 times over the year, in the invoice table there will be 500 lines for that item, and each line will have 500 image records, even though that image is exactly the same for all 500 records.

Is there any way to make SQL Server know that we only need 1 cached image for each item, and to just use the same thing when duplicates are found?

Thanks a lot, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually need to eagerly load the image, can you not just get all the related data and pull the images on request?

Comment: The problem is the salespeople export our reports into Excel, so they want an excel file with all the images. Sure I can create a report where you click into a line and then it shows that image, but the problem with that is when you back out of it, you have to run the report again, which is annoying. And also, this wouldn't export into excel.

Comment: Does this query have any use outside of building this excel report?

Comment: *"returns 500,000 records and it does so within 45 seconds, which is reasonable enough."* honestly, 45 seconds for 500,000 rows with that query isn't "reasonable" in my opinion; that's really slow.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I'm not really sure, but what would be your suggestion ?

Comment: Even in Excel, if you wanted to display an image 500 times, it would need to be in the file 500 times. Perhaps you're outputting to the wrong tool or something. Perhaps, for example, you should be displaying a webpage as then you can have multiple references to the same image, and that image only needs to be retrieved once. Of course, this would likely also mean changing the design and storing the images in a file path, not the SQL Server (and you store the path in SQL Server instead). I feel like there's multiple (design) issues here compounding to make an even bigger problem.

Comment: @user7959439 well like I said in my previous comment, I would abstract the image retrieval into a separate process. So for this report, you get all the data, then in a different process get the image and put it in X amount pf places where it is needed

Comment: Is there a reason you use temporary tables? Creating them from your permanent tables takes time. It's possible that you'll get a performance boost from refactoring all those queries into one: that would pull your IMAGE and other data from their tables and deliver it directly to your output without needing to copy it to the temp table.

Comment: From a disk I/O point of view you're making the query 3 times slower than it needs to be by spooling to tempdb since 1) it needs to read images from LOB storage in the main database (which may or may not be answered by page cache), 2) it then needs to write images to LOB storage in tempdb and 3) it needs to read images from LOB storage in tempdb again to return the final result set.

Comment: @O.Jones Thats what I used to do before, had everything in one query with no temps, but it still ran super slow.